# Extend jQuery with modified .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I am building a site for both mobile/touch devices as well as desktop non-touch devices.
To help with eliminating the 300ms delay on jQuery .click events for touch devices I am using the tappy library, which works beautifully.

```
https://github.com/filamentgroup/tappy
```

That being said, I only want to bind this 'tap' event where necessary and want to bind a regular .click event if the device is non-touch. I know tappy's 'tap' event will fire for non-touch devices, but I'd rather only use it where necessary since there are a few quirks documented.

Up to now I have been writing switch functions each time I want to do this, which looks like this:

```
if ($('html').hasClass('no-touch')) {
    $('.sidebar').find('.strip').find('.explore-wrapper').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.sidebar').addClass('active');
    });
} else {    
    $('.sidebar').find('.strip').find('.explore-wrapper').bind('tap', function() {
      $(this).closest('.sidebar').addClass('active');    
    });
 }
```

I'd like to extend jQuery and write my own version of .click, maybe called 'tapClick' so that my code could function like:

```
$('.sidebar').find('.strip').find('.explore-wrapper').tapClick(function() {
    $(this).closest('.sidebar').addClass('active');
});
```

I started to try and write my own extension, but couldn't get it...any help would be appreciated:

```
// Custom tap/click bind
$.extend({
    tapClick : function(callbackFnk) {
        if ($('html').hasClass('touch')) {
            $(this).bind('tap', function() {
                if(typeof callbackFnk == 'function') {
                    callbackFnk.call(this);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(this).click(function() {
                if(typeof callbackFnk == 'function') {
                    callbackFnk.call(this);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Probably this will help http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that I ended up using that solves the problem.

```
$.fn.extend({
    tapClick:function(callback) {
        if ($('html').hasClass('touch')) {
            return $(this).click(callback);
        } else {
            return $(this).bind('tap', callback);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer has showed up in the Low Quality Posts review queue because you have not included any explanation of your code. Generally it improves an answer when the code is explained.

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting [jQuery.fn.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/) for [jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

e.g.,

```
    $.extend({tapClick:function() {console.log(this)}}); 
    $.fn.extend({tapClick:function() {console.log(this)}}); 

    $.tapClick(); // function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
    $("html").tapClick(); // [html, ...]
```

```js
       $.extend({tapClick:function() {console.log(this)}}); 
    $.fn.extend({tapClick:function() {console.log(this)}}); 
    
    $.tapClick();
    $("html").tapClick();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I ended up taking your code and modifying it to suit my needs, now it works great. The key was using 'this' and passing it back.